# How can I match capital ÅÄÖ in mysql regexp

Tags: mysql, regex, unicode

When I do a REGEXP comparison in MySQL, I get some strange results for the capital versions of the Swedish characters. I am using the utf8_swedish_ci collation and I want to find capitalized words.

`SELECT 'Öster' REGEXP BINARY '^[A-ZÅÄÖ][a-zåäö]+$'` should return 1 and `SELECT 'öster' REGEXP BINARY '^[A-ZÅÄÖ][a-zåäö]+$'` should return 0, but I get the opposite result.

```
SELECT 'Öster' REGEXP BINARY '^[A-ZÅÄÖ][a-zåäö]+$' # returns 0 (incorrect)
SELECT 'öster' REGEXP BINARY '^[A-ZÅÄÖ][a-zåäö]+$' # returns 1 (incorrect)
SELECT 'Söder' REGEXP BINARY '^[A-ZÅÄÖ][a-zåäö]+$' # returns 1 (correct)
SELECT 'söder' REGEXP BINARY '^[A-ZÅÄÖ][a-zåäö]+$' # returns 0 (correct)
```

If I use REGEXP instead of REGEXP BINARY, 'söder' will also match (which is not what I want), but even then 'Öster' is not a match.

What should I do about this?

Comment: Note that the _ci in utf8_swedish_ci stands for case insensitive. Make sure whatever application and terminal you run in also uses utf-8, such that the SQL you enter in is actually sent to mysql as utf-8

Comment: @nos Yes, this is why I use `BINARY`, which seems to work for A-Z, a-z and åäö but not for ÅÄÖ.
I use phpMyAdmin and have changed the server connection collation to utf8_swedish_ci.

Answer (score 3):

I realize you've found a fix, but wanted to explain why it works. `REGEXP` in MySQL doesn't work with "characters" but [works with bytes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html). Å, Ä, Ö, å, ä, and ö are all two byte characters in UTF-8. When they are used in the regex `[ ]` construct, the regex engine sees each of these bytes individually and only attempts to match one byte rather than the two bytes that composes the whole character. If you decompose these characters into their constituent bytes, you can see why some matches happened by fluke.

Your fix of using the regex `'^([A-Z]|Å|Ä|Ö)[a-zåäö]+$'` technically works, but it's by chance that the bytes which compose å, ä, and ö don't actually allow any other unintended well-formed UTF-8 character strings to accidentally match.

I would recommend using `'^([A-Z]|Å|Ä|Ö)([a-z]|å|ä|ö)+$'` for clarity.

Comment: Can a capitalized word begin with É in Swedish?

Answer (score 0):

After more experimenting, I found that changing the capitals part of my regex like this fixes the issue:

```
SELECT 'Öster' REGEXP BINARY '^([A-Z]|Å|Ä|Ö)[a-zåäö]+$'
```

I don't understand why this produces a different result.