# REGEXP not working as expected, inside a PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have this issue with mysql when querying a DB inside PHP.

The PHP code is:

```
$Query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM theTable WHERE fieldValue REGEXP 'Dom-R[eéèêë]my'";
$DBR = mysql_query($Query,$Connection);
```

I am expecting this query to get things like, I mean find the number of those:

```
Dom-Remy
Dom-Rémy
Dom-Rèmy
...etc...
```

But I get nothing, I mean zero. What is wrong in the code? I have tried several variations, all equally not working.

Comment: you got a curly quote in there `‘` :), but I doubt that is the issue.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18592428/1959948

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18851217/1959948

Comment: The natural assumption is that no data actually matches the pattern.

Comment: The curly quote was only a typo. This is not the issue. I fixed it.

Comment: Rather than being just learning PHP, the mysql_query extension is the only one I know of. I have read about MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions, but haven't got into using them yet.

Comment: It's toast. You better move on for your own health and safety. PDO isn't hard. That link there will walk you through the basics in twenty minutes.

Comment: OK I certainly should learn the new extensions (and will soon), by the way is PDO any better than MySQLi? But I presume my present issue is solvable in any extension (old or new). Am I wrong? Or is it much easier using the new interface?

Comment: I suggest that the debate between PDO and mysqli is a "religious war"; neither side is a clear winner.  (If I am wrong, let the battle ensue!)

Comment: The regex question stands, regardless of which of the 3 interfaces is used.  "Get away from 'mysql_*' is good advice, but does into impact the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is subject of **Unicode** characters.

What happens is that `e,é,è,ê,ë..` in your example is not a single letter but 2 because the tilde counts as a character as well. This brings lots of complexities and rules that needs to be followed in order to meet Unicode rules.

You could do something like: `([\x{0049}-\x{0130}])` to search letters with tildes but this expression may vary depending if you are going to use this expression on .net, java, javascript or php.

You could also check what code each character represents here:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=%C4%B0&preview=entity

Comment: I've tried to follow you suggestion, but it gets tricky, there must be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As per official [website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) specification, MySQL regex is matched in byte-wise fashion

> The REGEXP and RLIKE operators compare characters by their
>   byte values and accented characters may not compare as equal even if a
>   given collation treats them as equal.

If you can match any character in place of `[eéèêë]`, this should be sufficient:

```
$Query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM theTable WHERE field REGEXP '^Dom-R.+?my$'";
```

Comment: No this cannot match any character of course. Otherwise I would not bang my head with specific European characters.

Answer (score 0):

If

- the column's `CHARACTER SET` is `utf8` or `utf8mb4`, *and*
- your connection between client and mysql server is also either of those character set, *and*
- you are not using `COLLATION utf8_bin`, *then*

'Dom-Remy' = 'Dom-Rémy' = ...

`WHERE ... = ...` and `WHERE ... LIKE ...` will abide by the above.  `REGEXP` (`RLIKE`) cannot be used, for the reasons already discussed.

[*This*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html) shows what is equal (for `=` and `LIKE`.)

If you are simply searching a string for `Dom-Remy`, use

```
fieldValue LIKE '%Dom-Remy%`
```

and instead of regexp/rlike

If you have something more complex that needs `REGEXP`, then start a new question with the details.